# Apache Toree 0.1.x - NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.classServerUri()

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-1.6, apache-toree

I have created a Scala kernel for my Jupyter notebook using Spark 1.6 on CDH 5.12. I am using Apache Toree 0.1.x.
I have installed the python package toree 0.1.0 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toree/0.1.0).

And the kernel was installed with the following command.

```
jupyter toree install --spark_home=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/lib/spark
```

However when I create a create a new Notebook using the kernel I am getting the following error.

```
17/12/20 11:35:51 [WARN] o.a.t.b.l.StandardComponentInitialization$$anon$1 - Locked to Scala interpreter with SparkIMain until decoupled!
17/12/20 11:35:51 [WARN] o.a.t.b.l.StandardComponentInitialization$$anon$1 - Unable to control initialization of REPL class server!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.classServerUri()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreter.classServerURI(ScalaInterpreter.scala:515)
    at org.apache.toree.boot.layer.StandardComponentInitialization$$anon$1.createSparkConf(ComponentInitialization.scala:179)
    at org.apache.toree.kernel.api.Kernel.createSparkContext(Kernel.scala:348)
    at org.apache.toree.kernel.api.Kernel.createSparkContext(Kernel.scala:370)
    at org.apache.toree.boot.layer.StandardComponentInitialization$class.initializeSparkContext(ComponentInitialization.scala:102)
    at org.apache.toree.Main$$anon$1.initializeSparkContext(Main.scala:34)
    at org.apache.toree.boot.layer.StandardComponentInitialization$class.initializeComponents(ComponentInitialization.scala:87)
    at org.apache.toree.Main$$anon$1.initializeComponents(Main.scala:34)
    at org.apache.toree.boot.KernelBootstrap.initialize(KernelBootstrap.scala:87)
    at org.apache.toree.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at org.apache.toree.Main$.main(Main.scala:23)
    at org.apache.toree.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Same error is reported under TOREE-358 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOREE-358)

Comment: I'm using apache-spark 2.2.1. I received the same error as yours initially when using Apache Toree 0.1. I tried to upgrade Toree using `pip install https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/toree/0.2.0/snapshots/dev1/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz` and now it works.

Comment: I normally use Spark 2.2.1 and Apache Toree 0.2 works fine with it. But, now I've got a requirement use Spark 1.6 on CDH 5.12 (Scala 2.10). That's why I installed Toree 0.1 which supports Scala 2.10.